# ¿Como se traduce la palabra inglesa "dank" en referencia a la calidad de la marihuana?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

En ingles la palabra "dank" se refiere a una combinación de factores. Su significado literal conlleva matices de frio, de humedad y de un olor malo y potente, pero mas frecuentemente se usa para referirse a la marihuana de alta calidad [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_names_for_cannabis#Slang_names_for_good-quality_cannabis). No se de cuál fuente proviene este significado, quizás es que la marihuana buena tiene buen olor, aunque el significado general es negativo. En cualquier caso, me pregunto si existe alguna palabra en español que tenga el mismo significado en cuanto a la calidad de la marihuana.

¿Hay una palabra en español con un significado similar?

Comment: Después de una búsqueda parece que, aparte de un par de referencias como *olor agridulce*, siempre se dice *olor/oler a [nombre local de marihuana]* o, a veces, calcando el inglés, *olor/oler a zorrino/mofeta/zorillo*.  Entonces como adjetivo, lo tienes algo chungo creo para el olor.  El uso de *dank* para referirse a marihuana parece venir del hecho de, después de curarse, todavía sigue estando algo húmedo. Seguramente habrá alguna palabra, pero dudo que también haga referencia al olor.

Comment: Voté a cerrar por no estar clara la pregunta, pero cambio mi voto si explicas a cuál audiencia quieres comunicar esta idea.

Comment: No hay razón para cerrar la pregunta. Está clara. Quiere saber como se dice en español, y puede haber más de una contestación.

Comment: Diría una audiencia informal. Si escribiera en inglés para una publicación científica, por ejemplo, no utilizaría la palabra "dank" sino algunos términos más específicos tales como "high-THC" o "potent" con el fin de comunicar conceptos exactos. Así que seguramente la audiencia hipotética del equivalente en español sería similar.

Answer (score 1):

El uso de "dank" en el contexto de la marijuana es jerga y comunica la conclusión opuesta de su uso normal, aunque describe las mismas cualidades. Lo que pasa es que con la marijuana la conclusión de que es un producto de calidad se basa en atributos similares a los que te indicarían que cualquier otro producto vegetal es de baja calidad o está podrido. El uso asumo viene de una actitud contra-cultura y de rebeldía, por razones obvias.

Por ser jerga, para encontrar una traducción apropiada hay que buscarla en la jerga del público a quién se dirige la traducción. Además, para hacerlo más difícil, es casi imposible encontrar que la jerga tenga un origen similar.

Por ejemplo, en Puerto Rico algunas personas usan la palabra "pangola" para describir marijuana de baja calidad. ¿Quién le mete mano a esa traducción? Yo no me tiro. Demasiado fría el agua. *8P

Answer (score 1):

No sé nada sobre este tema pero buscando en el internet parece que esta frase es equivalente a *good weed*:

**buena mota**

Por otra parte, encontré un [artículo](https://www.vice.com/es_latam/article/a3yqw4/la-guia-definitiva-para-catar-marihuana-como-un-profesional) que termina con esta conclusión:

> Aunque ésta es una guía para catar marihuana con estándares
>   profesionales, la realidad es que en México pocas personas pueden
>   escoger entre diferentes plantas, ya que la ilegalidad obliga a los
>   usuarios a recurrir al mercado ilegal. Esto hace muy difícil conseguir
>   la marihuana deseada con los efectos esperados. Aún así, el día en que
>   podamos comprar **motas peludas y apestosas** llegará.

Parece entonces que "motas peludas y apestosas" se usa como "dank".  Pero desgraciadamente cuando busqué esta frase no logré confirmar.

Comment: ¿No hay otros significados de mota que podrían resultar confuso?

Comment: @Obie2.0 - Parece que *mota* se usa en México y parte de Centroamérica.  Véase https://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=mota y https://dle.rae.es/?id=PvSWmD7.